# adding different sized columns of DF as row to another DF

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a for loop wherein I load in a DF from a .xls file format. I would like to get the values from one of the columns and add those as a row to a different DF. unfortunately, the column length differs along the loop creating a mismatched columns error. to solve this most of the time I create a series out of the column data yet this triggers another error "InvalidIndexError: Reindexing only valid with uniquely valued Index objects" which I am not familiar with what the problem exactly is.

see the code below code containing both the loc and append method for filling the dataframe.

```
for i in range(0, len(files)):

    temp = pd.read_excel(files[i], info["Sheet name"], skiprows=int(info["Rev " + str(rev_num)]["Start"]), nrows=int(info["Rev " + str(rev_num)]["Nrows"]), usecols=info["Rev " + str(rev_num)]["Columns"], header=1)
    #collection.append(pd.Series(temp[info["Data column"]].values.tolist()), ignore_index=True)
    collection.loc[len(collection)] = temp[info["Data column"]].values.tolist()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to be able to resolve your issue, you can create a list of lists then convert the list of lists to a pandas dataframe, then transpose it.

```py
collection = []
for f in files:
    temp = pd.read_excel(f, info["Sheet name"], skiprows=int(info["Rev " + str(rev_num)]["Start"]), nrows=int(info["Rev " + str(rev_num)]["Nrows"]), usecols=info["Rev " + str(rev_num)]["Columns"], header=1)
    collection.append(temp[info["Data column"]].values.tolist())


# assuming this is the list of lists that you have appended
collection = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9,10]]
df = pd.DataFrame(collection).T
print(df)
```

Comment: thanks for the help Eyad Sibai. It fully worked, only note was that the transpose was not needed in my case but that was quick to spot.